# Python help command

Tags: python

How can Python's help information on a given module/function be obtained?

For example, to obtain information on scipy's chi2, the following commands:

```
>> from scipy.stats import chi2
>> help(chi2.pdf)
```

provide only general help:

> Help on method pdf in module scipy.stats.distributions:
>
> pdf(self, x, *args, **kwds) method of scipy.stats.distributions.chi2_gen instance
>
> Probability density function at x of the given RV.

etc.

How can the specific details be obtained? In this example something like:

> The function call is chi2.pdf(x, v) with v degrees of freedom.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `help()` function only displays the `docstring` of the object you're calling it on. If that object doesn't have one (or one that doesn't contain the information you're after), you will need to look at the documentation of the module/function/object you're using.

Answer (score 1):

If you are on Python3 it is better to invoke the help prompt first.

Python3> help ()

Then while in help prompt, type the method you are looking for

help> modulename.methodname ( if you know the modules and methods already ).

If you do not - then while in help prompt,

help> modules ( list all the modules ).

To see what methods nltk has go out of help and type

Python3> import nltk
Python3> dir (nltk)