# Is there a module with a help function?

Tags: python, documentation

I am using the python embedded version, and I know that this sounds weird, but in there, there isn't a help function.

Is there a module that can show help about functions and classes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20996298/13376511):

> The `help()` function only displays the `docstring` of the object you're calling it on. If that object doesn't have one (or one that doesn't contain the information you're after), you will need to look at the documentation of the module/function/object you're using.

So it seems that you're pretty much limited to however much documentation your Python version ships with. But, considering that it's an embedded version, the system you're running on likely doesn't have enough storage to make storing documentation practical. If `help()` is undefined, then I doubt that there are any docstrings in the first place. If you were to get `help()` to work, then there wouldn't be any documentation for it to access anyway.

Rather than getting together a makeshift `help()` function, you're probably better off just using a different computer and reading the documentation online.

Now if the docstrings do exist, that is in the `.__doc__` property, all the `help()` function really does is read the docstring and display it in a pretty way. So all you need to do is display the `.__doc__` in a way that looks pretty to you. You could also try to use [CPython's `help()` implementation](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2cd1c87d2a23ffd00730b5d1648304593530326c/Lib/_sitebuiltins.py#L88) by using/porting [pydoc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pydoc.html#module-pydoc).

Comment: I am meaning that `help` is undefined, not that there are no docstrings.

Comment: @John If `help()` is undefined, then I doubt that there are any docstrings in the first place. Basically, if you were to get `help()` to work, then there wouldn't be any documentation for it to access anyway.

Comment: I am using the `.__doc__`s right now, trying to create a `help` function

Comment: They are still in there.

Comment: @John If the docstring does exist, then you should be able to use [CPython's `help()` function](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2cd1c87d2a23ffd00730b5d1648304593530326c/Lib/_sitebuiltins.py#L88) by installing/porting [pydoc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pydoc.html#module-pydoc).

Comment: All the `help()` function really does is read the docstring and display it in a pretty way. So all you need to do is display the `.__doc__` in a way that looks pretty to you.

Comment: Great! How about copying that to the answer so other people can easily see it too?